# Apache Flink streaming word count aggregate over lines

Tags: apache-flink, word-count, flink-streaming

I've bumped into a class of issues which are non-existent in batch processing, but seem non-trivial for streaming case. Let's consider the classic word count example:

```
lines
  .flatMap(_.split("\\W+"))
  .map(word => (word, 1))
  .keyBy(0)
  .sum(1)
```

This will print the result for every word in the stream, e.g.:

```
input: "foo bar baz foo"
output: (foo, 1) (bar, 1) (baz, 1) (foo, 2)
```

What I'd like to do instead is to process each line as a whole and only then print the result, i.e. use a window over each line:

```
input: "foo bar baz foo"
output: (foo, 2) (bar, 1) (baz, 1)
```

Obviously, neither time-based nor count-based windows are applicable here. What is the correct way to tackle the problem?

Comment: You need to merge `flatMap` and `map` into a single operator, and also do some pre aggregation (ie counting how often each word is in a sentence). Thus, input foo bar baz foo" would be transformed into "(foo, 2) (bar, 1) (baz, 1)" *before* the keyBy

Comment: I need to parallelise operations on individual words before grouping them back.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by "window over each line". I think adding more input lines to your example and showing the desired output would help here.

Comment: @FabianHueske I mean that I want to count words per line, i.e. wait until all words in a line are processed before emitting any output. This is just an example, the general problem is: split each input record into different parts (aka flatMap), process these parts in parallel and then aggregate them (group by each initial record) for further processing.

Comment: I.e. logically it looks like this: `lines.map(line => line.split("\\W+").map(processWord).reduce(aggregateWords))`, which is what Mathias suggested, but the processing function is quite heavy, so I'd like to parallelise it somehow: `lines.flatMap((_.id, _.split("\\W+"))).map(processWord).groupAllRecords(_.id).reduce(aggregateWords))`

Comment: You could also add a (random) line id to the word you emit in flatMap and use "lineId + word" as key.

Comment: How do I know when I consumed all records with a given lineId and should do some aggregation? That's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Processing both words and lines in parallel is not possible even in batch mode because nested `groupBy` (or `keyBy`) is not supported in Flink. If however, you want the streaming version of the following batch word-count:

```
lines
  .flatMap(line => (lineId,word,1))
  .groupBy(0)
  .reduceGroup {aggregateWords}
```

where `aggregateWords` iterates over words for that specific key and counts them, then you can implement it in the following way: for each line you emit the words along with a special record at the end, then you use a GlobalWindow with a custom trigger that fires once the special record is received.

A streaming version of the previous batch job could look like:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

    env.fromElements("foo bar baz foo", "yes no no yes", "hi hello hi hello")

            .flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<String, Tuple3<Double, String, Integer>>() {
                @Override
                public void flatMap(String s, Collector<Tuple3<Double, String, Integer>> collector) throws Exception {
                    String[] words = s.split("\\W+");
                    Double lineId = Math.random();
                    for (String w : words) {
                        collector.collect(Tuple3.of(lineId, w, 1));
                    }
                    collector.collect(Tuple3.of(lineId, "\n", 1));
                }
            })
            .keyBy(0)
            .window(GlobalWindows.create())
            .trigger(new Trigger<Tuple3<Double, String, Integer>, GlobalWindow>() {
                @Override
                public TriggerResult onElement(Tuple3<Double, String, Integer> element, long l, GlobalWindow globalWindow, TriggerContext triggerContext) throws Exception {
                    if (element.f1.equals("\n")) {
                        return TriggerResult.FIRE;
                    }
                    return TriggerResult.CONTINUE;
                }

                @Override
                public TriggerResult onProcessingTime(long l, GlobalWindow globalWindow, TriggerContext triggerContext) throws Exception {
                    return TriggerResult.CONTINUE;
                }

                @Override
                public TriggerResult onEventTime(long l, GlobalWindow globalWindow, TriggerContext triggerContext) throws Exception {
                    return TriggerResult.CONTINUE;
                }
            })
            .fold(new HashMap<>(), new FoldFunction<Tuple3<Double, String, Integer>, HashMap<String, Integer>>() {
                @Override
                public HashMap<String, Integer> fold(HashMap<String, Integer> hashMap, Tuple3<Double, String, Integer> tuple3) throws Exception {
                    if (!tuple3.f1.equals("\n")) {
                        hashMap.put(tuple3.f1, hashMap.getOrDefault(tuple3.f1, 0) + 1);
                    }
                    return hashMap;
                }
            }).print();

    env.execute("Test");

}
```

Output:

```
{bar=1, foo=2, baz=1}
{no=2, yes=2}
{hi=2, hello=2}
```

Comment: Omg, that looks complicated! In batch mode this problem doesn't exist because you don't need to trigger anything - you just collect all existing records for each key in `groupBy`, while in streaming mode you need to know when you collected enough and need to trigger.